# Different states doesn't show template content

Tags: angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, state

I have a basic Index.html file which following structure:

```
<body class="{{$state.current.name.replace('.','-')}}">
    <div ui-view>
        <div ng-include src="'partials/menu.html'"></div>
        <!-- <div ng-menu class="ui top blue sidebar menu active"></div> -->

        <div class="view-height-100"></div>
    </div>

 ...
</body>
```

When I am in the login state, it's working very well:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'partials/login-area.html',
        controller: 'LoginController',
      });
```

**But, when I am routing to the user.management state, nothing gets shown** (but Chrome is loading the template, so I can access the scope and the .html file is there):

```
$stateProvider
  .state('user', {
    url: '/:buildingName',
    controller: 'CurrentBuildingController',
    data: {
      access: ['user']
    }
  })
  .state('user.management', {
    url: '/management',
    templateUrl: '/views/management.html',
    controller: 'ManagementController'
  })
```

> Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent state simply **must have target** for its child *(unless we use absolute naming to target some super parent, but it is another approach)*

```
.state('user', {
    url: '/:buildingName',
    template: "<div ui-view></div>",
    controller: 'CurrentBuildingController',
    data: {
      access: ['user']
    }
  })
```

see that we now have **`template: "<div ui-view></div>",`** which will serve as a view target for any child state **`'user.xxx'`**

Check also:

- [AngularJS UI-Router : Abstract state + child states not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32741205/1679310)

EXTEND - let child to target the index.html

We can use absolute naming and child will then be injected directly into index.html. There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DWFNMATslGBJ2CVnJSrR?p=preview) *(by intention parent won't load, it does not have any template)*

```
  .state('parent', {
      url: "/parent",
      //templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  })
  .state('parent.child', { 
      url: "/child",
      views: {
        '@': {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
          controller: 'ChildCtrl',
        }
      }
  })
```

Check this for more info:

#### [Angularjs ui-router not reaching child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27457460/1679310)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But now the div overrides my div-container inside the index.html. How can I make sure it's just adding and not overriding the container?

Comment: In case I did understand what you want.. I extended answer, added example.. it should help to now how to with UI-Router ...